raise NoReverseMatch(msg) as I executed my code
I have added the code to enable the remove option on the cart. the following error occurs. please help me in this regard
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'remove_cart_item' with arguments '(2,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/remove_cart_item/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<cart_item_id>[0-9]+)/$']

cart.html
    <td class="text-right"> 
    <a href="{% url 'remove_cart_item' cart_item.product.id cart_item.id %}" class="btn btn-danger"> Remove</a>
    </td>

urls.py file of the carts app
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.cart, name='cart'),
    path('add_cart/<int:product_id>/', views.add_cart, name='add_cart'),
    path('remove_cart/<int:product_id>/<int:cart_item_id>/', views.remove_cart, name='remove_cart'),
    path('remove_cart_item/<int:product_id>/<int:cart_item_id>/', views.remove_cart_item, name='remove_cart_item'),

]

views.py file of the carts app
def _cart_id(request):
    cart = request.session.session_key
    if not cart:
        cart = request.session.create()
    return cart

def add_cart(request, product_id): 
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)  #get the product
    product_variation = []
    if request.method=='POST':
        for item in request.POST:
            key=item
            value=request.POST[key]
            
            try:
                variation=Variation.objects.get(product=product, variation_category__iexact=key, variation_value__iexact=value)
                product_variation.append(variation)
            except:
                pass

    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id = _cart_id(request))  #get the cart using the cart_id present in the session
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(
            cart_id = _cart_id(request)
        )
    cart.save()

    is_cart_item_exists = CartItem.objects.filter(product=product, cart=cart).exists()
    if is_cart_item_exists:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.filter(product=product, cart=cart)
        # existing_variations ->database
        # current_variations -> product_variation
        # item_id -> database
        ex_var_list = []
        id = []
        for item in cart_item:
            existing_variation = item.variations.all()
            ex_var_list.append(list(existing_variation))
            id.append(item.id)

        print(ex_var_list)

        if product_variation in ex_var_list:
            # increase the cart item quantity
            index = ex_var_list.index(product_variation)
            item_id = id[index]
            item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, id=item_id)
            item.quantity += 1
            item.save()
        else:
            # create a new cart item
            item = CartItem.objects.create(product=product, quantity=1, cart=cart)
            if len(product_variation) > 0:
                item.variations.clear()
                item.variations.add(*product_variation)     
            item.save()
    else:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
            product = product,
            quantity = 1,
            cart = cart,
        )
        if len(product_variation) > 0:
            cart_item.variations.clear()
            cart_item.variations.add(*product_variation)
        cart_item.save()

    return redirect('cart')

def remove_cart(request, product_id, cart_item_id):
    cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id = _cart_id(request))
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    try:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product = product, cart = cart, id=cart_item_id)
        if cart_item.quantity > 1:
            cart_item.quantity -= 1
            cart_item.save()
        else:
            cart_item.delete()
    except:
        pass
    return redirect('cart')

def remove_cart_item(request, product_id, cart_item_id):
    cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id = _cart_id(request))
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product = product, cart = cart, id=cart_item_id)
    cart_item.delete()
    return redirect('cart')
    
def cart(request, total=0, quantity=0, cart_items= None):
    try:
        tax = 0
        grand_total = 0
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id = _cart_id(request))
        cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(cart=cart, is_active=True)
        for cart_item in cart_items:
            total += (cart_item.product.price * cart_item.quantity)
            quantity += cart_item.quantity
        tax = (total * 2) / 100
        grand_total = total + tax
        
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass # just ignore
    context = {
        'total': total,
        'quantity': quantity,
        'cart_items': cart_items,
        'tax': tax,
        'grand_total': grand_total,
        }

    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)

trace stack
Internal Server Error: /cart/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\carts\views.py", line 124, in cart       
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 312, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 446, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Education Department, Government of Punjab\Desktop\Django demos\GreatKart\env\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'remove_cart_item' with arguments '(2,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/remove_cart_item/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<cart_item_id>[0-9]+)/$']


So what are you rendering?

Can you edit your question and show a complete stack trace please?

SO auto-suggested that this question might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699066/noreversematch-at-cart-reverse-for-productview-not-found-productview-is-n?rq=2  Is it any help?

Is that the only {% url 'remove_cart_item ... %}.

Please don't repost closed questions, edit the original to resolve the closure reason instead. I'm closing this for now to the canonical for this problem. Your question currently lacks a [mre] (specifically the reproducible part), if you add one in we'll point out the specific issue to you. You're showing us the wrong template tag for your issue, note that the error only shows one argument while your template tag even if it gets the arguments wrong would show 2 arguments (with empty strings if they are wrong).

Also you're showing us the wrong view, the error says NoReverseMatch at /cart/ so you should be showing us the view for that URL and its template.

I have solved the above-said bug using this code in the Cart.html file.   ```
 Remove</a
```